# how to remove headers at the beginning of the html file using jsoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am using jsoup to parse the html file. I have successfully removed all the tags from Html but the thing is, I also want to remove the headers at the beginning of the file.
For example:

> WARC/1.0
>
> WARC-Type: response
>
> WARC-Date: 2012-02-10T20:37:13Z
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Server: Apache

Here is my code:

```
 static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException 
 {
     byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
     return new String(encoded, encoding);
 }
 String file=indexer.readFile("C:\\Users\\umair\\Downloads\\Compressed\\Assignment 1 Data IR\\Assignment 1 Data IR\\corpus\\corpus\\corpus\\clueweb12-0000tw-14-17002.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
 System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(file).text());
```

Any idea how can i remove these headers?

Comment: That's not an HTML file, that's an HTTP response. You should use an HTTP parser.

Comment: Could you please provide me some line of codes for it?

Comment: I've never worked with JSoup, and I have no idea where your `s` variable is coming from. But you're somehow operating on the raw response, when you should be using the response body only.

Comment: i wrote the complete code now.

Comment: I anticipate that `jsoup` is perhaps not the solution that you're looking for. For parsing with `jsoup` you need to have a pure `html` file. You'd even encounter problems if the html is not properly written (like if all the tags aren't properly closed). Now here you have a pure html response so jsoup won't parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
doc.body()
```

to get only the body of the HTML document without any headers. This, of course, assumes that you are processing proper HTML documents.

Comment: could you please tell me where should i use this line of code in my code? Actually i am new in HTML parsing, i dont know how to modify my code. my code is already giving me text without tags.

Comment: You can do `Jsoup.parse(file).body().text()` if you don't need anything else.

Comment: That means you do not have a proper HTML document - you are trying to process something else. The text in your question is not HTML file.

Comment: It contains HTML tags but the file type is not HTML, its type is 'file'. I need to parse 10,000 such files.

Comment: The document you displayed in your question does not look like HTML document regardless of its extension.

Comment: So is there anyway to parse it?

Comment: doc.html() will return page html content without HTTP headers